# Do bidendates occupy cis position always?

Tags: stereochemistry, coordination-compounds

https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Inorganic_Chemistry/Coordination_Chemistry/Properties_of_Coordination_Compounds/Isomers/Stereoisomers%3A_Geometric_Isomers_in_Transition_Metal_Complexes

In example 1.1, it is written that en which occupy only adjacent positions.....is it true for any bidendate for octahedral isomer?

Comment: It surely depends on the size of the specific ligand. Big floppy ligands might well be able to occupy opposite positions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not impossible to have a [trans-spanning ligand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-spanning_ligand), but they seem to be rarer than cis-ligands due to their increased length and greater potential for steric strain. While en is too small of a ligand to reach trans-positions, it is possible with significantly longer ligands.

It seems octahedral ones are even rarer than their square planar counterparts, but there has been at least one reported synthesis of a [trans-spanned octahedral](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticlePDF/1999/DT/a807574c)$^1$ that I could find. In the linked paper, they report the synthesis of trans-$\ce{[Ru(Cl)(trpy)(C3SPAN)]}$ where trpy = 2,2:6,2-terpyridine and C3SPAN=$\ce{Ph2PC6H4CH2O(CO)(CH2)3(CO)OC6H4PPh2}$.

$\hspace{25ex}$[image: trans-spanned ruthenium complex]

1. C. Bessel, et al. Chem. Soc., Dalton Trans., 1999, 2281–2292

Comment: Interesting, but isn't that for square-planar? Or does it apply to octahedral as well?

Comment: @gilleain good catch, I jumped on that too quickly. It seems to also be possible for octahedral as well. I will try to link to a paper.

Comment: So the question was solved on the basis of assumption or taking the case which is more bound to happen?

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla for the example you gave, it could only be cis because the en ligand is too small to be trans-spanning.

Comment: can en liagand be trans spanning in any other case?

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla I don't believe so. The ligand itself just doesn't reach far enough to access sites that aren't right next to each other (cis).

Comment: But in my book ,for [Cocl2(en)2] complex,the en liagand configures itself to show both cis and trans isomers.Is it bc it is square planar?

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla thats the difference between trans and trans-spanning. $\ce{CoCl2(en)2}$ can be cis or trans because the two en groups can be separated by 90 or 180 degrees, but neither of the en groups binds to sites 180 degrees apart, which is trans-spanning.

Comment: So square planar can have cis-trans while it is difficult for octahedral...am i correct

Comment: @HydrousCaperilla I think you still have trans and trans-spanning confused. In the picture on my post, the long ligand is trans-spanning because one of its ends is bound on the opposite side of the metal from the other. When you have two of the same ligand bound on opposites sides of the metal, we call that trans. CoCl2(en)2 is actually octahedral because en is a bidentate ligand.